# How to recursively fetch collection with all subcollections?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firestore called 'steps' and inside steps collection I have lots of documents and subcollections called 'substeps' in each steps document. I need to create array which will have all the steps and substeps inside that I could use this [component](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tree), so the array should look like this

```
let steps = [
  {
    step: 1,
    id: '1'
    substeps: [
      {
        step: '1.1'
        substeps: [
          {
            step: '1.1.2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to crate recursive functions with will fetch all the substeps if they are exists

I tried to create function which should fetch all the subcollections, but I don't know how to finish it, so below example of what I tried, but notice function not finished and it is only first steps
Here is [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

```js
fetchAllStepsDeep (request) {
    //this.steps = array of objects with step data
    let result = []
    let requestLocal = this.$firebaseFirestore.collection('steps_for_classes')

    for (let i in this.steps) {
        result.push(this.steps[i])
        requestLocal.doc(this.steps[i].id).get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log('Document data:', doc.data())
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log('No such document!')
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting document:', error)
        })
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to retrieve all the subcollections inside collection and create one big array with other child arrays of objects? I use vue framework, so maybe this can be helpful

Thanks

Comment: You have to know all the names and paths of all the subcollections, and query them all separately.  There is no "recursive fetch" operation in Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

If the subcollection is always called `substeps`, you can create a helper function to handle the recursion

```
function getSubstepsOf(docRef, path, result) {
  docRef.collection("substeps").get((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      result.push({ path, doc });
      getSubstepsOf(doc.ref, `${path}/substeps/${doc.id}`, result);
    });
  });
}
```

And then call it with this from your existing code:

```
getSubstepsOf(doc.ref, doc.id, result);
```

Comment: yes, this is how I wanted to fetch data, but I don't know how to create this big array where all the child arrays and objects should be. I need to specify the path in this result array and don't know how

Comment: I added how to track the path in the recursive call in my answer. Any time you need to do something recursively, pass it as a argument into the function, and build it up as you recurse.

Answer (score 0):

If interested in Firestore 9 you can do it by array of strings:

```
let pathSegment: string[] = [parentKey, "comments"] 
doc(db, "channels", channelKey, "comments", ...pathSegments, commentKey)
```